# u-boot debug using BDI2000 PowerPC4xx

Tags: u-boot

I'm trying to figure out what's going on while trying to debug a U-boot port. I've got U-boot loaded on my board and by BDI2000 set-up for debug. As I step through start.S I keep running into this error:

```
(gdb) si
314     mtspr   SPRN_SRR0,r0
(gdb) si
315     mtspr   SPRN_SRR1,r0
(gdb) si
316     mtspr   SPRN_CSRR0,r0
(gdb) si
317     mtspr   SPRN_CSRR1,r0
(gdb) si
320     mtspr   SPRN_MCSRR0,r0
(gdb) si
321     mtspr   SPRN_MCSRR1,r0
(gdb) si
322     mfspr   r1,SPRN_MCSR
(gdb) si
323     mtspr   SPRN_MCSR,r1
(gdb) si
333     lis r1,0x0030   /* store gathering & broadcast disable */
(gdb) si
Cannot access memory at address 0x300000
(gdb) si
_start_440 () at start.S:334
334     ori r1,r1,0x6000    /* cache touch */
Cannot access memory at address 0xfffff03c
(gdb) bt
#0  _start_440 () at start.S:334
#1  0xfffff18c in rsttlb () at start.S:480
Backtrace stopped: frame did not save the PC
```

This is my first board bring up so any pointers you might have would be very helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason GDB only reads in the asm for the module being run. By stepping into other areas with the BDI I'm able to stepi from GDB without the "Cannot access memory" issues.

If you have questions feel free to send me a message.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be PowerPC code.  My experience suggests that your memory address is not yet mapped.  Start up code by default will access Non-Volatile Memory (NVM) code (ex: ROM, EEPROM, Flash...) and it is the responsibility to set or define where RAM is located.  Generally, this information is pulled from NVM, and written into a Memory Management device or within the PowerPC chip in order to make the Processor aware of RAM.  Without seeing the entire code it is difficult to assess if it is set up properly.  The other possibility is that the config file of the BDI is not describing what is at address 0x300000